# Ionic ble.startNotification has been overwritten (Android)

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

As I said above, when I tried to do a batch operation of Bluetooth on an older phone (Android 9, the Bluetooth version may have been produced in 4.2 ~ 2017), the reconnection of the device caused the message of the ble.startNotification callback of the previous device to be overwritten, but this did not happen on the newly produced phone (Andriod 12, Bluetooth version 5.2).

Is it because the phone is too old? It bothers me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After unremitting efforts, we have finally solved this problem. If you also encounter this problem, please focus on checking the code that scans Bluetooth and connects to Bluetooth.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).